# Data only shown when application starts

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have two problems.
First, I managed to connect a DB which I created in visual studio and connected it to the form, but the changes are shown only when the form is started from the .exe file. Could someone explain to me why?
Second, know I want to connect a second WinForm to the same DB, but I could not find the correct way of doing it.
Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezkQa.png)

```
string cn_string = Properties.Settings.Default.TenantListConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cn_connection = new SqlConnection(cn_string);
        if (cn_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cn_connection.Open();
        }
        string sql_Text = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Tenants";
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_Text, cn_connection);
        adapter.Fill(tbl);

        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Tenant Name";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Room Number";

        listBox1.DataSource = tbl;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! `First, I managed to connect a DB` and how's this because your error image say's otherwise because of an error. Also, `but the changes are shown only when the form is started from the .exe file`, there's nothing happening on the `Form_Load` is there somewhere where you might be calling the `Button1_Click` event? To be honest, your assertions are not matching the image nor the code... Can you please update your post to include more focus so we can better assist you?

Comment: Amongst the comments above, no need to check for the connection state, it will always be closed when you create a new instance of `SqlConnection`. Also, look into `using` statements to dispose of objects when you are done with them.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TableName` is always a bad sign.